A tag for crime, forensic psychology, criminology, etc?
There are quite a few questions that relate to criminal behaviour. There is a field in psychology called "forensic psychology" that specifically deals with this. There are also social science disciplines such as law and criminology. There are also more specific topics such as "aggression", "sexuality", "anti-social behaviour" and so on.

Should we have a tag for this?
If so, what would be a good tag?

Example questions:

Is there a correlation between online and offline vandalism?
Do widespread brain toxins explain violence rates?
Do victims of parental abuse and neglect become abusive or neglectful parents?


My preference would be for a tag like forensic-psychology with a redirection from crime or criminology.
I think this forensic-psychology stays truer to the focus of the site. However, I feel that people less knowledgable of the field are more likely to successfully use a tag like crime or criminology.

I agree with this, with the note that we don't have a [tag:crime] tag yet, so we probably shouldn't set up a tag synonym unless someone actually uses that tag.

Forensic psychology works for me, crime seems a bit too distant from the focus of the site
